# why remove header section after delete row swift

Tags: ios, swift

```
self.interstsListTableView.beginUpdates()
self.interstsListTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
self.interstsListTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: indexPath.section == 0 ? self.viewModel.arrayDisenabled.count - 1 : self.viewModel.arrayEnabled.count - 1, section: indexPath.section == 1 ? 0 : 1)], with: .fade)
self.interstsListTableView.endUpdates()
```

When I delete a row from one section and insert it into the second section, the header of the second section disappears, although there are elements in these two sections.

Comment: Header will remove if there is no other rows remaining in it.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini There are lines and it still removes the header.